# Using base verbs in a sentence

Tags: verbs

I've just began to read “Atlas shrugged” in English and noticed a strange structure in the third paragraph:

"Why did you say that?" asked Eddie Willers, his voice tense.

I'm interested in the last part:

His voice tense

I'm struggling to understand what does it mean. Rules I know say that you should use base verb form when you want to express an emotion. But is “tense” an emotion? Why “tensed” isn't used there? Why not “his voice is tense”?

Comment: "Tense" is an adjective, not a verb, in your example. It's a verbless clause meaning "his voice was tense".